# Error when update database using in mysql

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I using command update in wamp server with table `mobile_brands(id, display_size)`

```
UPDATE `mobile_brands` 
SET display_size="240 x 400" WHERE id=80,
SET display_size="240 x 400" WHERE id=81;
```

When i run command is error, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documention for [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), you need multiple update expressions:

```
UPDATE `mobile_brands` SET display_size="240 x 400" WHERE id=80;
UDPATE `mobile_brands` SET display_size="240 x 400" WHERE id=81;
...
```